# AppleScript: Searching application name with mixed character encoding

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, applescript

I am writing a simple script to search application from iTunes store. The app does the following:

-- Read the application from a user input (text field in a dialog box)

-- Take the app name in a variable and keystroke the app name in the search text field in       iTunes (Right Top Corner).

-- Press enter (keystroke return) .

The problem I am struggling is:

When the user inputs a Japanese text as a app name, I need to detect that it is a Japanese text and need to change the keyboard input type to JP before keystroke to the search field.

And sometimes the app name contains both EN and JP character set.

Can someone help me how to detect character encoding of every character with AppleScript?

Thanks and Best Regards

Rahman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might just use `itunes` URLs:

```
itunes://ax.search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?term=漢字
```

```
text returned of (display dialog "" default answer "")
do shell script "u=itunes://ax.search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa
q=$(printf %s " & quoted form of result & " | xxd -p | tr -d '\\n' | sed 's/../%&/g')
open $u/search?term=$q"
```

You can also use the clipboard to insert text:

```
try
    set old to the clipboard as record
end try
set the clipboard to "漢字"
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "v" using command down
end tell
delay 0.1
try
    set the clipboard to old
end try
```

If the clipboard is empty, trying to get it results in an error. `the clipboard` is like `the clipboard as text`, but `the clipboard as record` also includes other types. Simulating keystrokes is usually faster than clicking menu bar items, and clicking menu bar items doesn't work in full screen windows or when an application doesn't have a menu bar. Without the delay, `set the clipboard to old` would sometimes be run before the text would get pasted.

Or in this case you could use UI scripting:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    reopen
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTunes"
    tell text field 1 of (get value of attribute "AXMainWindow")
        set value to "漢字"
        set selected to true
    end tell
    keystroke return
end tell
```

Comment: This is just GREAT !!!
 set value to "漢字"

Solved my problem..Thank you very much !!!

Comment: Even though I thought the clipboard concept while sleeping yesterday night, but you mentioned that concept too. At least my thought was approved ... LOL. Any way thanks again .